# check checkbox manually not working

Tags: jquery, html

```
 $('.checkboxInTable').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selected = $(this);
    selected.prop('checked', true);
    //selected.attr('checked', true);
   }
```

`.prop()` don't add anything in the HTML

attr add `checked="checked"` but visually nothing change

Jquery v1.9

Comment: why do you want to set the attribute? instead of the checked state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be useful to bind change event on document if you are creating dynamic checkbox.

try using e.stopPropagation() instead of e.preventDefault() and also remove return false. Returning false in jQuery is equivalent to e.stopPropagation() + e.preventDefault(). e.preventDefault() prevents the checkbox from being checked.

```
$(document).on("change",".checkboxInTable", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected = $(this);
        if(!$(selected).is(":checked")) // check first if the checkbox is checked or not
          $(selected).prop('checked', true); // if not then check it, BUt when you want to uncheck, it will not allow you by using this method.
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

change the event from `click()` to `change()`
try this:

```
           $('.checkboxInTable').change(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();

              var selected = $(this);
              selected.prop('checked', true);
           });
```

Comment: Thank you but i think that e.preventDefault(); doesn't work with change. I would like to prevent the checking then check manualy

Answer (score 0):

[Update] Try this fix. [EDIT] Sorry for duplication, someone else posted the same solution before me @Alessandro Minoccheri.

```
$('.checkboxInTable').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var selected = $(this);
    selected.prop('checked', true);
}
);
```

===============
Regarding your code
This line preventing the selection of the checkbox, so it will be always the default as it viewed while the page load. i.e. seems as read only?

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Your code will run correctly if what you want is upon check the checkbox, it will remain checked.

```
$('.checkboxInTable').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();

        var selected = $(this);
        selected.prop('checked', true);
        //selected.attr('checked', true);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I skirt the problem using

onChange="plzCheck(this)" on my html checkbox

then myCheckbox.checked = true;